# Tkinter's ScrolledText not adjusting to input

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll

How can I get the scrollbar to co-operate with the text widget instead of just sitting there?
The text widget gets a real time input so the scrollbar needs to be dynamic.

Thank you!

here's the widget's block:

```
def text_widget(self):

    self.text_window = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self, height=100, width=500, bg="gray", wrap=tk.WORD)
    self.text_window.insert(tk.END, "")
    self.text_window.grid(row=5, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky="we")
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that the `self` is much larger than the `ScrolledText`.Could you show us a minimal example?

Comment: The height option is too big.  Either set it to suitable value, or change `sticky` to `"nsew"`.

Comment: @acw1668 you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to acw1668!!

working code:

```
def text_widget(self):

    self.text_window = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self, bg="gray", wrap=tk.WORD)
    self.text_window.insert(tk.END, "")
    self.text_window.grid(row=5, column=1, rowspan=3, sticky="we")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I am using pack so I get: "cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack"